# FormData object always returns empty object

Tags: javascript, form-data

i have a simple form

```
 <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data" id="form_id">
    <Row>
      <Col >
        <input
          name= "more"
          title = "More"
          type="file"
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </form>
```

Once the value of input is changed, i catch that event in another method 
and when i tried to create a FormData object and pass the form to the constructor of FormData, it still give me an empty object, here's what i tried to do:

```
  var f =new FormData(document.getElementById('form_id'));
  f.append("file","some value");
```

can any one suggest a solution please ?

Comment: Are you using some kind of library or is this xml? Since I didn't know that <Row> and <Col> are valid html tags.

Comment: Can you create a snippet?

Comment: @Shilly yes i'm using react-bootstrap, but this isn't my problem
why i got an empty object?

Comment: It isn't an empty object. It is a FormData object.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, no idea how the interaction between react form syntax and FormData objects works.

Answer (score -1):

```
var f = new FormData(document.getElementById('form_id'));
f.append("file", $('input-selector')[0].files)
```